# Regular expression for matching short date pattern in any culture

Tags: c#, regex, date, date-format

I need a custom regex to math short date pattern(etc. "M/dd/yyyy", "dd/mm/yyyy", "yyyy/mm/dd",...depend on culture..) then I can get day,month,year to parse that format like this:

```
    string input = "03/24/2013";
    Match m = Regex.Match(input, @"^(?<day>\d{1,2})/(?<month>\d{1,2})/(?<year>\d{4})$");
    if( m.Success )
    {
        DateTime d = new DateTime(int.Parse(m.Groups["year"].Value),
                                  int.Parse(m.Groups["month"].Value),
                                  int.Parse(m.Groups["day"].Value));

    }
```

but! this expression not support all various formats so

**require** :

- Accept only '/' as separators.
- Valid all short date pattern(Date only,also Time would be great) in various cultures (etc, en-US, th-TH, jp-JP,...). Is this possible, actually I just need to know which part is year, month or day but I couldn't find it anywhere. Please help me...
- Valid common range: day [1-31]{1-2}, month [1-12]{1-2}, year[1600-9999]{4}

Comment: Why do you need a regex for this rather than doing it by iterating through the cultures? Bear in mind that the year "1600" isn't the same across different cultures, for example - are you only interested in the *Gregorian* year?

Comment: Use `DateTime.TryParse`, cycling through the different cultures. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9h21f14e.aspx  Note, however, that you have an ambiguity problem. The string "03/12/2013" could be March 12th or December 3rd, depending on the culture.

Comment: @JonSkeet, I have no idea about that year,found on regexlib.com,just ignore it. anyway iterating through the cultures umm.. this interesting can you give me more hint(code),thanks

Comment: @nhahtdh: It's not that there's anything special about that year - it's that different cultures number years in different ways, so having one blanket date range across cultures isn't very meaningful.

Comment: @nhahtdh , Parse won't work in my case I don't know user culture/Locale region setting(asp.net only IE support) my FF or Chrome couldn't, so best I can do..get date.toLocaleFormat(FF ,still no idea for Chrome),  return datetime string,thus come  across my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Jim and I suggested, you can just iterate over all cultures:

```
foreach (var culture in CultureInfo.GetCultures(CultureTypes.SpecificCultures))
{
    DateTime result;
    if (DateTime.TryParseExact(text, "d", culture, DateTimeStyles.None,
                               out result))
    {
        // Valid - return, or whatever
    }
}
```

Note that ["d"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/az4se3k1.aspx) is the standard format string for a short date pattern. Alternatively, you could use `culture.DateTimeFormat.ShortDatePattern`.

Comment: Thanks again, for bring me to the light.